# ReactJS & Material UI - ClickawayListener is not working properly in the Shadow DOM

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, shadow-dom

I'm trying to build Micro Front End applications using ReactJS and Material UI framework. As a part of it, I was trying to embed a react application into the main React App using ShadowDOM.

I got the application running and working except when opening a popover, dialogs, modal, or date picker the ClickAwayListener is not functioning as expected meaning not closing.

Please suggest a way to fix this or show me a workaround to get the application running.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-bp5jx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround:

First, create a click listener on your shadow root to trigger a CustomEvent called `closeModal`.

```
const shadowRoot = document.getElementById('root').attachShadow({open: true});
let mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
mountPoint.id = "portal";

mountPoint.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let event = new CustomEvent('closeModal',{bubbles: true, cancelable: false});
    shadowRoot.dispatchEvent(event);
});

ReactDOM.render(themeProvider, mountPoint);
```

Then, when the popover or modal or date picker or dialog opens, create another event listener

```
document.getElementById('root').shadowRoot.addEventListener('closeModal', this.handleClose);
```

Once the modal is closed by the `handleClose` function, remove the event listener

```
document.getElementById('root').shadowRoot.removeEventListener('closeModal', this.handleClose);
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `ClickAwayListener` is being used in your CodeSandbox link, but I would guess that this issue is because you didn't wrap the inner element in an element that can accept a `ref`. Try wrapping the child element in a `<div>` and see where that gets you. :)

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work as expected. Hence created custom events to tackle the issue.